# Ошибка с пушем обьетов в массив, как пушить в чипы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Это код авто комлпита:

```
onChooseParticipant = participant => {
  const { participants } = this.state;
  participants.push(participant);
  this.setState({ participants });
};

onSearchParticipants = searchText => {
  return ReferencesApi
    .getEmployees(searchText)
    .then(response => response.map(employee => ({
        label: employee.fullname,
        responsibleRole: employee.jobPosition,
        value: employee.personId,
      })
    ));
}
```

Этот выбор идет при выборе направления этот метод смотреть вниз:

```
DocumentsApi
  .getApprovePersons(territory, this.state.selectedOrganization)
  .then(items => {
    let test = items.map(it => {
      return { 
        value: it.personId,
        label: it.fullName,
        responsibleRole: it.responsibleRole
      };
    });

    this.setState({ persons: test, participants: test });
});
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается  при выборе куда едешь он достает *Согласующих* и пушит их в массив `participants` и так же при автокомплите *Согласующие* тоже при выборе он пушит и добавляет в массив и выводит в чипы.

1. Почему-то не могу сделать правильно либо пушится с выбора направления куда в массив но не отоброжается на фронте.
2. Либо ты выбираешь согласующих в автокомплите и они добавляются, но все ломается при выборе направления

Как сделать что бы пушилось правильно с отображением при выборе куда и потом правильно добавлялось через автокомплит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, как Вы это делаете - пораждает мутацию состояния и непредвиденное поведение. Давайте рассмотрим более подробно Ваш код:

```
const { participants } = this.state; // получили значение
participants.push(participant); // не правильно изменили значение (мутировали его)
this.setState({ participants }); // вызвали мутацию состояния
```

> Никогда не мутируйте `this.state` напрямую, так как более поздний вызов
>   `setState()` может перезаписать эту мутацию. Относитесь к `this.state` как
>   к иммутабельному объекту.

Ссылка на документацию: [**Состояние компонента - `state`**](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

---

Пушить в массив без мутаций можно через [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (создает новый массив на основе существующего, не изменяя исходный, а значит не вызывает мутации):

```
this.setState({
  participants: [...this.state.participants, participant],
});
```

Еще один альтернативный вариант через [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) (он возвращает новый массив, не изменяя исходный, а значит не вызывает мутации):

```
this.setState({
  participants: this.state.participants.concat([participant]),
})
```

Еще один вариант через вызов функции и Spread syntax:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  participants: [...prevState.participants, participant]
}))
```

Полезная ссылка для ознакомления: [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26254086/5275890)