# Правильно ли так изменять state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

У меня есть массив объектов, у них нет точного распорядка и идентификации , но мне нужно найти объект с определенным `id` и изменить в нем свойство `crossout`.

Я это сделал так:

```
completeClick(e) {
    const id = e.target.id;
    let result = this.state.tasksArray.find(item => item.id == id);
    result.span = true;
    this.setState({ state: 1 }); 
}
```

Но из за того что я не могу изменить свойство напрямую(`this.setState()`), я изменяю его через костыль `result.span = true` . Как изменить код так , что бы я могу найти объект и изменить его напрямую через `setState`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Документация по React гласит (и я полностью с ней согласен):

> Никогда не мутируйте `this.state` напрямую, так как более поздний
>   вызов `setState()` может перезаписать эту мутацию. Относитесь к
>   `this.state` как к иммутабельному объекту.

Мутация состояния [state](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) приводит к непредвиденному поведению, так называемые сайд эффекты. Поэтому предлагаю Вам следующий способ изменения элемента массива из состояния:

```
completeClick(e) {
    const id = e.target.id;
    // ищем индекс элемента в массиве, удовлетворяющий условию поиска
    const index = this.state.tasksArray.findIndex(item => item.id == id);

    // если элемент был найден - выполним следующий код
    if (index != -1) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        tasksArray: {
          ...prevState.tasksArray,
          [prevState.tasksArray[index].span]: true,
        },
      }));
    }
}
```

Такой подход гарантирует нам, что состояние не будет мутировать. Полезные ссылки:

- [React: How do I update state.item[i] on setState?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38378350/5275890)
- [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26254086/5275890)
- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- [Ошибка с пушем обьетов в массив, как пушить в массив state?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025168/189339)

Если данный подход выглядит громоздким или сложным, то можно попробовать сделать это через метод [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

> Метод `Object.assign()` используется для копирования значений всех
>   собственных перечисляемых свойств из одного или более исходных
>   объектов в целевой объект. После копирования он возвращает целевой
>   объект.

В Вашем случае должно получиться как-то так:

```
completeClick(e) {
    const id = e.target.id;

    // клонирование исходного массив из state (можно и через spread syntax)
    const tasks = Object.assign({}, this.state.tasksArray)

    // ищем индекс элемента в массиве, удовлетворяющий условию поиска
    const index = this.state.tasksArray.findIndex(item => item.id == id);

    // если элемент был найден - выполним следующий код
    if (index != -1) {
      // меняем значение найденного элемента
      tasks[index].span = true;

      // присваиваем новое значение, без мутации
      this.setState({ tasksArray: tasks });
    }      
}
```

Но есть обратная сторона медали, если объект имеет сложную вложенную структуру, метод `Object.assign()` может начать работать не так, как хотелось бы. Для решения подобных вопросов можно воспользоваться готовым методом из *lodash* библиотеки: [`_.cloneDeep(value)`](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) - этот метод рекурсивно клонирует значения.

Comment: Здравствуйте, а есть более простой подход? Я просто новичек и синтаксис глаза режит

Comment: @mbfilipp здравствуйте, есть способ еще, к примеру через Object.assign  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: спасибо, который раз вы меня выручаете)